# Zoom extension to multilayer boundaries of several KML

Tags: openlayers

I have a web page that uses openlayers 5 and has several layers, each one of them extracts the data of one kml. How can I zoom in and show all kmls on the screen

```js
 var vector1 = new ol.layer.Vector({
    source: new ol.source.Vector({
      url: 'vector1.kml',
      format: new ol.format.KML({
        extractStyles: true
      })
    }),
    style: styleFunction
  });
  var vector2 = new ol.layer.Vector({
    source: new ol.source.Vector({
      url: 'vector2.kml',
      format: new ol.format.KML({
        extractStyles: true
      })
    }),
    style: styleFunction
  });


var raster = new ol.layer.Tile({ // TileLayer
    source: new ol.source.Stamen({
      layer: 'toner'
    })
  });

  var view = new ol.View({
    center: [0, 0],
    zoom: 1  // 14
  });


  var Layers =  [raster,vector1,vector2,vector3,vector4];
  var map = new ol.Map({
    layers: Layers,
    target: 'map',
    view: view
  });
```

I have a web page that uses openlayers 5 and has several layers, each one of them extracts the data of one kml. How can I zoom in and show all kmls on the screen

Answer (score 0):

It's not going to be very efficient because the sources will load asynchronously in a random order and there is no event to indicate all features have been added, each feature fires an event, but building and fitting an extent as they load will get there eventually

```
var Layers = [raster,vector1,vector2,vector3,vector4];
var extent = ol.extent.createEmpty();
Layers.slice(1).forEach(function(layer){
  layer.getSource().on('addfeature',function(){
    ol.extent.extend(extent, layer.getSource().getExtent());
    map.getView().fit(extent, { size: map.getSize() });
  });
});
```